# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an asp.net web page, there is a texbox, i want to make sure the text entered is less than 3 characters, the code i wrote is

```
<input type="text" name="searchcatid" size="15" onblur="test_length(Index.searchchatid)" />

<script>

function test_length(testcontrol) {


    var teststring = testcontrol.value;

    if (teststring.length >= 3) {
        alert("ID must be 3 or fewer characters!");
        testcontrol.focus();
    }
    else {
    }


} 


</script>
```

and I get the error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined", whenever i enter something, I have no idea what goes wrong, since im really new in asp.net, not even sure my code would actually work, hope someone could help me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Pass the input element in a proper way:

```
<input type="text" name="searchcatid" size="15" onblur="test_length(this);" />
```

It would be even better if you [registered your eventhandlers via JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) instead of using inline events.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the problem , please check

`name="searchcatid"`  `Index.searchchatid`
The spelling `searchcatid` doesn't match